# ControllerContext.HttpContext.User is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have an MVC project that I converted from C# to VB and I have problem.  The project has an extension method, IsSysAdmin(), for the ControllerBase class that attempts to get the logged in user name. The web site is designed to use Windows Authentication and has the appropriate entries in the root level web.config to enable it, including an entry to allow only logged in users to have access to the site (deny users="?").  The IsSysAdmin() function is called by a Razor reference in the Shared Layout View for the site.

Here is the VB Code for the function:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function IsSysAdmin(ByVal controller As ControllerBase) As Boolean
    Dim bIsSysAdmin As Boolean = False

    Dim loggedInUser = controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name

---- Other code

    Return bIsSysAdmin

End Function
```

Here is the C# code:

```
    public static bool IsSysAdmin(this ControllerBase controller)
{        
    bool bIsSysAdmin = false;

    string loggedInUser = controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

---- Other code

    return bIsSysAdmin;
}
```

The C# version has no issues.  The loggedInUser variable gets the actual logged in user name.  But, in the VB version, loggedInUser is blank.

Obviously I'm missing something here, but I don't know what.

Comment: I assume you've checked that `controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` does actually contain a value?  If it does then the problem doesn't not lie within the extension method, and you can therefore ask your questions more succinctly

Comment: And you've turned off anonymous access in web.config with the <anonymousAuthentication> element or IISExpress settings?

Comment: Yes, I have checked controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name using the VS Debugger.  It has a value in the C# version but does not have a value in the VB version.

Comment: Thank you Fran.  My VB project had Anonymous Authentication Enabled.  The C# project had it disabled.  Changing the VB project to disable Anonymous Authentication resolved my issue.

Comment: Yeah.  On new projects that is set by default and you have to go an manually change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IISExpress settings for Visual Studio have Anonymous Authentication on by default.

You need to turn it off on the properties for the project.

1. Select you project in the Solution Explorer.
2. Click F4
3. Set Anonymous Authentication to Disabled
4. Set Windows Authentication to Enabled